# simultaneous database access question (Mysql,Sqlite?)

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

My basic problem is that i am trying to have two python programs run simultaneously and have access to the same database table. I feel like this should have a simple solution but it has passed my by so far.

All my attempts at this have caused the database(sqlite) to be locked and the program falling over.
i have tried being clever with the timing with how they programs run so that as one program opens the connection the other closes it, copying data from one database to another etc..  but this just gets horrible and messy very quickly and also a big goal in my design is that I would like to keep latency to an *absolute* minimum.

The basic structure is pictured below.

I should add too that program one - 'always running and adding to database' is in the milliseconds timeframe.
Program two can be in the multiple seconds range. Obviously none of my solutions have been able to come close to that.

[image]

Any help, steps in the right direction or links to further reading is greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: SQLite would not be the first database that comes to mind for streaming.

Comment: I can't say that I understand fully what you're trying to do, but look into [write-ahead logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

Comment: Roganjosh  thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Although your title mentions MySQL, in your question you are only using sqlite. Now, sqlite is a perfectly capable database if you only have a single process accessing it, but it is not good for multiple simultaneous access. This is exactly where you need a proper database - like MySQL.

Comment: So by switching over to MySQL proper I should be able to have simultaneous access/writing to a table? Is there no special framework I would need to factor in? Even as the short timeframes. Seems I had been working on the assumption that they were pretty much the same only varying in database size?

Comment: Databases like MySQL are intended for multiple simultaneous access. Obviously there are considerations about contention if you're doing large updates, and table locks when you modify the schema structure, but mulitple processes reading at the same time is definitely possible.